# how to change language on log message on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing code on google apps script platform. And, when I execute program and get error message, I have this error message in Japanese. You can see the picture below for the image of the error message.

[image]
I just want to change this language on this error message into English. Could you teach me how to do it?

I have already change the language setting by the way explained in the movie in the following link. However, it didn't work.

https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/how-to-change-the-language-settings-in-google-apps/

I also tried to change the language as [this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en) too. And then, my setting looks like:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [changing your account's language settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en)?

Comment: @lamblichus Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have already changed the language preference as the link you wrote. But, it doesn't work, either.

Comment: Did you try it in a script you created **after** changing the language preference? Also, have you tried disabling V8? Do you get any change in behaviour?

Comment: @lamblichus Yes, I executed it after changing the language preference. And, V8 is disabled. nothing changed for log message.

Comment: I said **created**, not executed.

Comment: @lamblichus Sorrry. I didn't created it after change the language. Do I need to create it again? Can I re-create it by copying the original spread sheet containing the script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210873/discussion-between-iamblichus-and-herbert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account language settings have to be changed following the steps specified [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en). The new settings only affect projects that were created after this change.

Error log message appeared in English after I create the spreadsheet and apps script from scratch.

New language setting and preference affect only for spreadsheet and apps script that are created after the setting is changed.

#### Reference:

- [Change language](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en)