# Telegram Bots API responds in foreign language to my API calls from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm using Google Apps Script for my Telegram Bot, using the webhook method. I'm using English for both Google Apps Script, and Telegram. However, my calls to the Telegram Bots API returns error messages in Dutch, forcing me to use Google Translate:

```
Exception: Verzoek voor https://api.telegram.org is mislukt. Foutcode: 404. Ingekorte serverreactie: {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"} (Gebruik de optie muteHttpExceptions om de volledige reactie te onderzoeken.)
    at sendMessage(Code:167:15)
    at start(Code:91:3)
    at doPost(Code:32:7)
```

How do I make it use English?

Comment: Can you try changing your account's language settings? [Change your language on the web](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en). Then try creating a new project since the new settings only affects the projects that were created after changing.

Comment: @Logan I have always been using English, and still am... I have no clue where they'd get Dutch from

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009021/how-to-change-language-on-log-message-on-google-apps-script